# IOS creating a dictionary makes code stuck

Tags: ios, objective-c

There is something weird with my code :

I have this (inside a function that is being called by an NSTimer).

```
NSLog(@" Adding object to array ");
NSLog(@"Match Id : %@",self.matchId);

NSDictionary *dict = @{@"matchId"   :    self.matchId   ,
                       @"homeTeam"  :    self.homeTeam  ,
                       @"awayTeam"  :    self.awayTeam  ,
                       };

NSLog(@" Adding object to array with Data : %@",dict);
```

I can see the first two logs, but the third one is not printed.
Then my timer is called again, I can see again the first two but the third one does not print again.

Any help that?

Comment: did you try to debug and see if the dictionary does not silently crash somewhere ?

Comment: There is no way that should get stuck. It should complete quickly or crash. Nothing in the middle.

Comment: make sure that `self.matchId`, `self.homeTeam`,`self.awayTeam` are not nil

Comment: First you have and extra coma at the end of your `NSDictionnary`

Comment: @Stasel that was it, I haven't checked all of them. Make it an answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that any (or several) of `self.matchId`, `self.homeTeam`, `self.awayTeam` are `nil`, throwing an exception (`NSDictionary` expects object values), and therefore skipping the third `NSLog` line.